# Is there any lib for crossplatform Camera like devices streams parsing?

Tags: c++, stream, capture, device

C\C++ lib for cross-platform device streams capturing (It shall find all devices in system and be able to give me their streams for encoding or filtering or any thing else). I want it to be cross-platrorm  So is there any lib like this, opensource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it meets your requirements, but what you ask sounds close to [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/features/).